# IIS / IIS express lifecycle with PostAuthorizeRequest called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-express

I'm hooking into the event `PostAuthorizeRequest` in the `IIS` lifecycle (pipeline mode) and whenever a request to a friendly url (no file extension. eg. /page1/page2) is unhandled (no redirect or no rewritepath) and there should be a 404, the `PostAuthorizeRequest` is called a second time (not initiated from the client: checked with fiddler) and this time the HttpContext.Current.User is null while it was set the first time.

I was not aware of this behavior and I'm having problem to understand what's happening! Is there anyone out there with some more info or a good explanation so I know how to relate to this :) ?

Or is it me doing anything wrong ?

EDIT:

Found the problem but not a solution.
It's the new System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler that's causing the behavior. Read more at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4.aspx

It seems like if I don't act on the first request it's causing a child request (to StaticFileHandler ?) where no authentication is invoked but still my PostAuthorizeRequest is triggered, causing all kinds of problem....
Context (eg Context.Items) is also cleared between requests.

So is there a way to avoid or detect this second child request ?